# Using Ajax to sort a table in MVC architecture

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller

How would i use AJAX to sort a table that is displayed from the database? 
I've seen a few examples but their MVC is completely different from what I am doing and im quite lost. Could someone provide some useful resources for this? Thanks. Here is my code.

View of the table

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>CustomerID</th>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Street</th>
    <th>County</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
    <th>Email</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php foreach ($customers as $customer) : ?>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $customer['customerID']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $customer['fname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $customer['lname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $customer['address']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $customer['street']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $customer['county']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $customer['mobile']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $customer['email']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Index.php action call

```
if ($action == 'view_customers') {

// call functions from the MODEL to get data from DB
$customers = get_customers();


include('./view/view_customers.php');

}
```

The model

```
function get_customers(){
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM customers';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these simple steps:

- add javascript listeners for `th` (CustomerID, FirstName, ...). When user click on this element you create ajax call to special url for getting data
- add url for getting data, i,e `/getCustomers?OrderByColumn=CustomerID&OrderDirection=Desc` where OrderByColumn define column for sorting and OrderDirection define direction
- in simple case this url will retrieve all html-table and you just replace old table with new one
- in more complicated case this url will retrieve json with data and you process it with your js code

Comment: Thanks, it all makes sense. Im using onclick events on the th tags. I just dont know how to implement the ajax and etc. All I've been shown is how to make something appear with ajax using a button.